# Need to make DevExtreme Dropdown box as read only

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, devextreme

I am using DevExtreme controls for my DotNet application. Now my issue is, I want to make one dxDropDownBox as read only while selecting cash mode. So for that my code is,

```
 var mode = $("#Mode1").dxSelectBox('instance').option('value');
    if (mode == 'Cash') {
        $("#PartyName").dxDropDownBox('instance').option('ReadOnly',true);
    } else {
        $("#PartyName").dxDropDownBox('instance').option('ReadOnly',false);
    }
```

But this code is not working. I tried many times but, not resolved. What is my mistake?

Help me please.

Comment: I resolved my issue

Comment: My search engine indexes this page first for "devextreme dropdown readonly" -- consider posting your solution for posterity.